# dynatree + asp.net UpdatePanel - make clicked nodes bookmarkable

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dynatree

Is there a option to make the nodes bookmarkable. 
Clicking on the nodes causes a postback. I would like to make that click bookmarkable. The tree should be opened the same way when calling the bookmark.

Any help would be appreciated.